# hide navbar on scroll down past x pixels and show on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide my navbar when scrolls down and show when scrolls up, but scrolls down occurs after the windows has been scrolled x amount of pixels down the page.( in the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/9hvju3oq/16/) after #section1 ) and if scrolls up shows the navbar immediately.I am using this code but I don't know how could I define a position.

```js
var scrollp=0;
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                // ask about the position of scroll

                if ($(this).scrollTop() < scrollp) {
                    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
                    scrollp= $(this).scrollTop();
                } else {
                    $('.navbar').fadeOut();
                    scrollp= $(this).scrollTop();
                }
            });
        });

    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the scrollTop in the else clause, like this:

```
... else {
    scrollp = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollp > fadeOutAfter) // Set fadeOutAfter to wherever you want the navbar to fade out
        $('.navbar').fadeOut();
}
```